# how to make a variable a group of variables in php

Tags: php, html, variables

I want to make a php variable a group of other variables so that I can put the new group of variables into a .txt file.
Something like:

```
    $txt = $_GET["html"]
    $txt2 = $_GET["js"]
    $txt3 = $_GET["php"]
    $txt4 = $_GET["other"]
    $text = $txt $txt2 $txt3 $txt4;
    $filename = fopen("config.txt", "w");
    fwrite($filename, $text);
    fclose($filename);
```

I have searched on Google and Stack Overflow, but nothing seems to solve my problem.

Comment: `.` is for concatenation. RTFM please.

Comment: You could also wrap in double quotes - `$text = "$txt $txt2 $txt3 $txt4";` in addition to concatenation - `$text = $txt . $txt2 . $txt3 . $txt4;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to combine multiple string values into one string value then the term you're looking for is "concatenate", which in PHP is done with the `.` operator:

```
$text = $txt . $txt2 . $txt3 . $txt4;
```